# Pass Custom array Data to another activity via intent

Tags: java, android, android-activity, arraylist

```
     final RecipientEditTextView emailRetv =
      (RecipientEditTextView) findViewById(R.id.email_retv);
      emailRetv.setTokenizer(new Rfc822Tokenizer());
       emailRetv.setAdapter(new BaseRecipientAdapter(this));
       DrawableRecipientChips[] chips = phoneRetv.getSortedRecipients();
```

I need to send DrawableRecipientChips[] chips  to another activity via intents. please how do i go about?.

DrawableRecipientChips[] chips is from this [libary](https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips)

Comment: You'll have to tell us something about the data type `DrawRecipientChips`.

Comment: @TedHopp i just posted a link to the libary

Comment: Since `DrawableRecipientChips` is an interface and not a class, the actual array elements can be almost anything. I don't think you can send the objects to another activity without knowing what they are (or unless they implement `Serializable` or `Parcelable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have complex objects that you need to pass from one `Activity` to another, you don't have to put them in the `Intent`. You can just put them in `public static` variables, like this:

in `ActivityA`:

```
public static DrawableRecipientChips[] chips;
```

in `ActivityB.onCreate()`:

```
// Get reference to the chips array from the previous Activity
chips = ActivityA.chips;
```

This isn't a perfect solution, because if Android kills your process and the user returns to the app, the `public static` variable will be null. But you can test for that case and then restart your app from the beginning if this happens.